Power BI Service Custom Download file name
I have several visual tables in a PBI report,  I´d like to export them with a custom filename like  "file_name_page_name_timestamp",  Is feasable  any DAX function where I can get the current report name and current tab name to  generate dynamically the exported file´s name?
Report Name:  ABC
Page:   Sales
exported file name:    ABC_Sales_AAAAMMDD 

btw   the timestamp is already done.

How are you exporting the files? If you are doing it automatically with a software solution, you can use the Power BI API to retrieve the page and report names: link
